# Check severeal boolean returns in same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

I have several bool elements and I am checking it if returns me false.

```
bool i = false;
        switch (idcount)
        {
            case 1: i = p1(); break;
            case 2: i = p1() & p2(); break;
            case 3: i = p1() & p2() & p3(); break;
            case 4: i = p1() & p2() & p3() & p4(); break;
            case 5: i = p1() & p2() & p3() & p4() & p5(); break;
            case 6: i = p1() & p2() & p3() & p4() & p5() & p6(); break;
            case 7: i = p1() & p2() & p3() & p4() & p5() & p6() & p7(); break;
            }
return i;
```

I want if one of p*() returns false in any case i returns false.
Is it right way or two false returns true?
I want all p*() return true i returns true..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `&&` (logical and) not `&` (binary operator)

like:

`p1() && p2();`

it will return true only if all `p*()` are true (same as `&`), but note that if first `p*()` will return false rest of expression won't be evaluated. In case of `&` whole expression will be evaluated

```
var functions = new List<Func<bool>>();
functions.Add(p1);
functions.Add(p2);
functions.Add(p3);
functions.Add(p4);
functions.Add(p5);
functions.Add(p6);
functions.Add(p7);
return functions.Take(idcount).All(x=>x());
```

try above it looks cleaner than switch statement and should examine if all first `idcount` entries are true same as switch case with `&&`

Comment: The result is identical. It's only how much of the expression gets evaluated that's different.

Comment: @MarceloCantos yes it's true, but I haven't mentioned that result will be different, I said that OP should use `&&` instead of `&` here

Comment: Sure, but by stating that `&&` “will return true only if all `p*()` are true”, you leave the reader with the impression that `&` does something else.

Comment: @MarceloCantos ok, it can be confusing, I'll change it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Of course your code should work as what you want, however I would like to use the following compact code:

```
List<Func<bool>> ps = new List<Func<bool>>();
ps.Add(p1);
ps.Add(p2);
ps.Add(p3);
ps.Add(p4);
ps.Add(p5);
ps.Add(p6);
ps.Add(p7);
var i = ps.Take(idcount).All(a=>a());
```

To use a normal for loop, you can do something like this:

```
var i = true;  
if(ps.Count >= idcount){
  for(int i = 0; i < idcount; i++){
    if(!ps[i]()) { i = false; break;}
  } 
} //else ???
```

Comment: You can use `ps.Take(idcount).All(x=>x());` isntead of aggregate here

Comment: @wudzik great, it blinded me for using the logic of aggregate, borrow your comment to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using [& bit wise operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) will cause all the expression to be evaluated even if you get the `false` in first `p1()`. You should use [&& logical operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2a723cdk.aspx) to combine the condition.

**Binary & operators** are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, & computes the logical bitwise AND of its operands. For bool operands, & computes the logical AND of its operands; that is, the result is true if and only if both its operands are true.
The & operator evaluates both operators regardless of the first one's value, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx).

**Conditional-AND operator (&&)** performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2a723cdk.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `&&` which is operator for logical (true/false) values.

```
i = p1() && p2();
```

`&` is a bitwise AND operator for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the invariant you've stated

> I want if one of p*() returns false in any case i returns false. Is it right way or two false returns true? I want all p*() return true i returns true..

your code is correct.

By using '&' you'll evaluate all functions. For Instance

```
case 5: i = p1() & p2() & p3() & p4() & p5(); break;
```

here if `p2()` returns false, `i` will still be false but p3, p4 and p5 will be avaluated(which may not be what you want).
If you don't want that extra evaluation use the short circuit operator - `&&` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var areAllTrue = p1() && p2() && ... && p7();
return areAllTrue;
```

This will evaluate to true only if each p*() returns true.